# When I try to use super(type, obj) to create a bound classmethod, there are some things different

Tags: python, super

I typed code like this

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def m1(cls):
        pass

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def m1(cls):
        print(super(B, B).m1)
```

Then I called B.m1 and the result was

```
<bound method A.m1 of <class '__main__.B'>>
```

According to the documentation of `super`, if the second argument is used, `super` will return a bound object, and the code show it works.

I know that method `__new__` is also a classmethod, so I type a test code like this

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        print(super(A, A).__new__)
```

I had thought that it would be same as the former one. But the result confuses me:

```
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x103e33cf0>
```

Then I turned to method `__init__` like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print(super(A, self).__init__)
```

The result was

```
<method-wrapper '__init__' of A object at 0x104f59da0>
```

which is different from a bound object of an instance.

```
class A:
    def m1(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def m1(self):
        print(super(B, self).m1)
```

The result is

```
<bound method A.m1 of <__main__.B object at 0x104f59da0>>
```

So I wonder that why the result is different between built-in object and custom-defined object?

Comment: Note: `__new__` is a **static method**, not a class method. See the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__): *`__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming. Nothing more. You are dealing with methods (descriptors) defined in C code versus methods defined in Python code.

There is no *functional* difference, there is really no need to worry about what amounts to implementation differences.

Comment: I found that if I try to use super(B, B).m1() without passing cls to m1, it works, but if I try to use super(A, A).__new__(), it doesn't work and I must use super(A,A).__new__(A) or just super().__new__(A).

Comment: @user9010294: `__new__` is *treated* as a class method but is not actually bound as such. It is instead a static method and you need to pass in the class manually.

Comment: I get it. Thank you for help